# Merging two datababases

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

UPD: Where from the requirement is coming.

My friend is using Mnemosine (http://mnemosyne-proj.org/) which is python program that uses sqlite as db. The issue that mobile version works only with one database file and my friend has already several. So he asked me if I can merge two databases.

So! I have two sqlite db files with same schema but different data.

Is there an automated way to include data from one file to another? I just need to insert additional values to dictionary tables and correctly insert values from other tables based on new ids.

Unfortunately there are no foreign keys defined so I need probably first specify columns/tables relationship. But in general, if I solve relationship issue, is it possible to merge dbs?

Answer (score 2):

You can open the database you want to merge into, then [attach the other database](http://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html).

```
ATTACH DATABASE "foo.database" AS foo;
```

Then you can access the other database's tables by prefixing it with the database's name and a dot:

```
INSERT INTO bar (baz) SELECT baz FROM foo.bar;
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not something that I'm looking for. I'm updating my question

Comment: You should be able to open the database with the `sqlite3` shell and do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

sqlite3 bar.db ".dump t1" | grep -v "^CREATE" | sqlite3 foo.db

That will put the contents of table t1 from bar.db into table t1 in foo.db.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will investigate dump possibilities